# bundle install gives error could not find email_spec-1.0.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to RoR. I have got to open a project that is already created. The folder did not contain bin folder, I copied the contents of bin folder from some other project (which runs and which I have created by following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)) to the current. Now when I move to the `path/to/bin/` and give `rails server`, it gives, could not find `somegem name` in any of the sources. try bundle install.

If I install the gem using `gem install gemname -v=versionnumber`, it installs properly. But if I give the command `bundle install` it gives the error

`could not find email_spec-1.0.0 in any of the sources`

I know copying files is not the correct way to do. But how can I try running the project? or how can we solve this error in particular.

.I also found that the particular version is yanked, I downloaded email_spec 1.0.0 from RubyGems.org from outside. How do I proceed now?

edit::
This is my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'recurly'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem "friendly_id", "~> 3.1"
gem "will_paginate"
gem "fastercsv"
gem 'meta-tags', :require => 'meta_tags'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'thin'
gem 'faye', '0.5.5'
gem 'rack-ssl', :require => 'rack/ssl'
gem 'localized_country_select'

group :development, :test do
gem 'ruby-debug'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'cucumber-rails'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'database_cleaner'
gem 'cucumber-rails'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'spork'
gem 'launchy'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'ruby_parser'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'email_spec'
end
```

Edit:

As per the comment, I deleted the Gemfile.lock and tried running bundle install again. Now the problem is, it gives the following error

`An error occured while installing linecache (0.46) and bundler can not continue. Make sure that gem install linecache -v '0.46' succeeds`

I tried giving the command  gem install linecache -v=0.46

and it gives some error Gemfiles will remain installed in C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\linecache-0.46 for inspection. 
Results logged to C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\linecache-0.46\ext\gem_make.out

This particular file has these contents:

```
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of 
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
```

what should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing **Gemfile.lock** and running **bundle install** again.

Comment: @Learner, share your Gemfile

Comment: I restored the gemfile.lock deleted again and proceeded. Now it gives this error `An error occured while installing linecache  (0.46)  and bundler can not continue. Make sure that `gem install linecache -v '0.46'  succeeds. I did the same and gave bundle install again, but to no use.